# Powerpoint not launching with VBA: waiting for OLE Action

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Im working with an Excel file with some macros, one of them made to create a PPT.

Tee problem come out when sometimes, the macro fails in launching the PPT App, and giving as result a "waiting for OLE Action" error.

To quick "fix" this problem, when it comes up there is 2 options:

1. Go to the Task Manager and finish PPT (but sometimes it doesnt appear)
2. Restart the pc

As I said in the option 1, sometimes the PPT App doesnt appear even in the Task Manager, so i have no other option than restarting the pc...

Did anybody else struggle with this problem? Someone knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a combination of both `GetObject` and `CreateObject` to work with PPT. Possible to share your code?